# Can I map through two arrays to get both to render to the same Card Component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

> I passed down the state on two arrays to the List Component
> user array and tweets array

```
{this.props.tweets.map(el, i => {
                     return (
                         <div className="tweetCard">
                             <Card
                                 name={users[i].name}
                                 username={users[i].username}
                                 pic={users[i].profile_image_url}
                                 following={users[i].public_metrics.following_count}
                                 followers={users[i].public_metrics.followers_count}
                                 userTweet={users[i].public_metrics.tweet_count}
                                 tweet={el.text}
                                 date={el.created_at}
                                 likes={el.public_metrics.like_count}
                                 retweets={el.public_metrics.retweet_count}
                                 replies={el.public_metrics.reply_count}
                             />
                         </div>
                     )
                    
                 })}
```

> Is there a way to be able to pass both states down at once and map through vs having two different map functions and having to pass state down separately?

Comment: Are you asking about concatenation of two arrays of the same type, or are you asking about having two arrays that you want to iterate through in parallel because the data is divided up among the two arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can concat those two arrays before the mapping them to the `Card` component.

Suppose the other array is called `otherTweets`, you should replace the first line with:

`{[...this.props.tweets, ...this.props.otherTweets].map(el, i => {`

There we are concatinating two different arrays into one using the **spread operator**